# Java - commons-io - listFiles non-recursively

Tags: java, apache-commons, fileutils, apache-commons-io

I want to use Apache Commons IO's [`FileUtils.listFiles`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to find all files in a directory but *do not want to perform the search recursively*.

I can list all files recursively like so:

```
FileUtils.listFiles(directory,
                    new RegexFileFilter(regex),
                    DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);
```

Here `DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY` **accepts** all directories, thus recursing completely. Looking at the JavaDoc for [`DirectoryFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/DirectoryFileFilter.html) I don't see any provided implementations that **rejects** all directories. I can implement it myself like so..

```
public class NonRecursiveDirectoryFileFilter extends DirectoryFileFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I figure if Commons IO includes a convenient `DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY` for recursive searching, there should be an equally convenient implementation for non-recursive searching, no? The JavaDocs suggest there are no extensions of `DirectoryFileFilter` provided in Commons IO. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @MrLore I actually didn't know about `File.listFiles`! =) I ended up finding a `FalseFileFilter` which does the trick but this is much cleaner, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to give credit here to [@MrLore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276341/mrlore) who noted that [`File.listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) does exactly what I wanted. As he put it, before redacting his comment, the CommonsIO's [`FileUtils.listFiles`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) is intended to offer more functionality and the use case I described doesn't need these extra features.

Answer (score 0):

Doi, found it..

[`FalseFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/FalseFileFilter.html)

> A file filter that always returns false.